# Get the mostly occured value in multiple columns of a table

Tags: sql, max

I have table which contains three columns Work, Cost, Duration. I need to get the maximum
occurred values in all three columns. If two values occurred same times, then return the 
maximum value from that two. Please see the sample data & result below.

```
Work    Cost      Duration
 5       2        6
 5       8        7
 6       8        7
 2       2        2
 6       2        6
```

I need to get the result as

```
Work    Cost    Duration
 6       2         7
```

I tried with the following query, But it is returning the value for one column, that too it is returning the count for all the values

```
select Duration, count(*) as "DurationCount" from SimulationResult
  group by Duration
  order by count(*) desc,Duration desc
```

Comment: What SQL are you using?

Comment: In statistics this is called the 'mode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
select * from
(select top 1 Work from SimulationResult
  group by Work
  order by count(*) desc, Work desc),

(select top 1 Cost from SimulationResult
  group by Cost 
  order by count(*) desc, Cost desc),

(select top 1 Duration from SimulationResult
  group by Duration
  order by count(*) desc, Duration desc)
```

Comment: Yes this does work, I made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3cc0/3/0) for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select max(t1.a), max(t2.b), max(t3.c)
from
(select a from (
select a, count(a) counta
from #tab
group by a) tempa
having counta = max(counta)) t1,
(select b from (
select b, count(b) countb
from #tab
group by b) tempb
having countb = max(countb)) t2,
(select c from (
select c, count(c) countc
from #tab
group by c) tempc
having countc = max(countc)) t3
```